# AMI from create-image not maintaining user-data modifications, but console Launch is

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

TL;DR: when launching an instance of an AMI created with CLI `aws ec2 create-image` the previous applied `user-data` is gone, whereas launching off an AMI created in the console has all `user-data` modifications.

**Scenario:**

I want to automate creation of a custom AMI for our use which itself is based on a regularly updated base AMI. Whenever I get a notification I take the new AMI ID and then run a script, which I'll excerpt from.

I spin up an EC2 instance to which I add `user-data` of some form. Create files, add packages, etc. This step is straight-forward and works.

```
# base_ami_id is set elsewhere
ec2_id=$(aws ec2 run-instances \
  --image-id ${base_ami_id} \
  --count 1 \
  --instance-type t2.micro \
  --key-name ${key_name} \
  --security-group-ids ${security_group} \
  --subnet-id ${subnet} \
  --user-data file://user-data.sh \
  --iam-instance-profile Name=${iamprof} \
  --output text --query 'Instances[*].InstanceId' \
)

echo "Instance ID is ${ec2_id}"
echo "Waiting for instance ${ec2_id} to run"
aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids ${ec2_id}
```

**NOTE**: At this point, I can `ssh` into the created instance and verify that `cloud-init` applied all my `user-data` correctly. All is well.

Taking the returned Instance ID, I create an AMI image, as per

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html

```
echo Create image from instance ${ec2_id}
image_id=$(aws ec2 create-image --name ${image_name} --instance-id ${ec2_id} --output text --query 'ImageId')
echo "image ID is ${image_id}"
echo "Waiting for image ${image_id} to be available"
aws ec2 wait image-available --image-ids ${image_id}
echo "Image ${image_id} (${image_name}) available"
```

Watching in the console, after a while I see my new AMI.

To test, I launch an instance off the AMI created by this step - and am surprised to find that my modifications are NOT in the instance! It's as if I had launched off the *original* AMI. Which makes no sense: as described above, the `user-data` was there when I did a test login. And as seen in the shell excerpt above, I used the return `$[ec2_id}` which I got from the `aws ec2 run-instance` stage, as basis for the AMI creation and not , inadvertently, some other ID.

Making this even more confusing, I use the console and test by doing a `Create Image` from exactly that running instance, the one with Instance ID `${ec2_id}` as above, which showed that all my `user-data` was there.

Then I launch an instance off *that* AMI - and won't you know it *has* all my modifications! Everything is there.

I've checked and triple-checked and I just don't see where/what I'm doing wrong! I thought maybe there's some extra command line options in `aws ec2 create-image` which is used in the console equivalent when making the API call. If there is, I can't see it.

What am I missing?!

It's like the AMI created from the console, off the same instance ID and the one from the CLI are different, but I've compared the ID numbers, they're definitely the same. You would think that using the right instance ID implies that the underlying snapshots and/or volumes would be the same, because `--instance-id` is the only value I *can* provide to create-image, right?

EDIT:

Following @Michael-sqlbot advice, I looked into the CloudTrail logs. Sadly that made this even more frustrating.

*EDIT of EDIT:
I have removed the CloudTrail logs, as they turned out not to be pertinent to the issue and its solution and would quite possibly only confuse things.*

Comment: Once you launch an instance (and able to login), then you will need to go and use option `create AMI`. This option is available from Actions list on your Instances page. You can select any created instance (which is running) and choose to create Image of it. Then you are able to use this newly created AMI / image in your further settings. You need to edit your Launch Settings, and where you last time chose Linux/Ubuntu, there you will need to select 'chose from your AMI' option and select the Image that you had created. Then proceed next and save settings. Now it will work for new instances.

Comment: I think you're completely missing the point: console works just fine, that *is* the point. It's CLI that is not working.

Comment: The console sometimes performs multiple API requests in response to a single user action.  You *might* find that the CloudTrail logs that are generated by performing the same steps with console vs cli would provide a useful clue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot dang! hadn't thought of that. I'll try that!

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue and how to fix it, and it may help others running into the same issue:

It turns out that using

```
aws ec2 wait instance-running
```

is NOT sufficient to ensure that all `user-data` is complete and has finished.

You may want to use

```
aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok
```

either in addition or instead. Even then you may want to be paranoid and add a simple `sleep` of several minutes to be certain!